# How to evaluate conditions passed in awk?

Tags: performance, awk

A script written in Bash passes arguments to an Awk, such as `sample_name==10`.

Awk then finds which column in a table corresponds to `sample_name`, and rewrites the argument corresponding to the left hand of the expression, such as as `$1 == 10`.

But I don't know how to actually evaluate the condition when it's stored as a variable. The problem is mainly because we want to be able to pass all kinds of conditions, including regular expressions back.

So, I have coded some workarounds, which has actually caused the script to blow up to beyond its original purpose.

```
 for (c in where_col) {
      ((where_math[c] == "==" && $where_idx[c] == where_val[c]) ||
      (where_math[c] == ">=" && $where_idx[c] >= where_val[c]) ||
      (where_math[c] == "<=" && $where_idx[c] <= where_val[c]) ||
      (where_math[c] == "!=" && $where_idx[c] != where_val[c]) ||
      (where_math[c] == ">"  && $where_idx[c] >  where_val[c]) ||
      (where_math[c] == "~"  && $where_idx[c] ~  where_val[c]) ||
      (where_math[c] == "<"  && $where_idx[c] <  where_val[c])) {
        #some action
      }
```

Although it works now, I'm looking for a way to do this more cleanly.

Comment: what's `where_math` contents?

Comment: Those are just condition operators like `==`, so at present it says if the operator is `==` then use `==`

Comment: I'd try to solve it but need more context

Comment: I'm just looking to evaluate a conditional statement stored as a variable. If the contents of `a` stored as `1==1` I'd like to say something like `if(a)` to evaluate to true.

Answer (score 1):

You would probably do this by meta-programming:

You'd *generate* the awk script to execute. The additional variable expansion step allows you to insert, e.g., `<=` in the code. But it takes some extra thoughts about reliability as you don't want to allow generating invalid or insecure scripts.

You probably can do this online with a here-doc in bash easily.

Answer (score 1):

Awk does not have the [eval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eval) type function you seek
but (as you are doing), it can be used to write an evaluator.

Maybe something along the lines of writing it 
with the language instead of in the language will get you closer.
Otherwise I'm not sure awk is your path of least resistance

```
awk -v "lhs=$lhs" -v "op=$op" -v "rhs=$rhs"

op == "==" {result = lhs == rhs}
op == ">=" {result = lhs >= rhs}
op == "<=" {result = lhs <= rhs}
op == "!=" {result = lhs != rhs}
op == ">"  {result = lhs > rhs}
op == "~"  {result = lhs ~ rhs}
op == "<"  {result = lhs < rhs}

END{ #some action involving result
}
```